# $.ajax to $.post convert howto

Tags: c#, jquery

```
$.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formContainer.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#myModal').modal();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#divLoading').hide();
            }
        });
```

how to convert this in `$.post` call

I try like:

```
$.post(url, { model: formContainer.serialize() }, function (data) {
                    $('#myModal .modal-title').html($link.text());
                    $('#myModal .te').html(data);
                    //  $('#myModal .te').html($.parseHTML(data)); // this remove existing the css
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                }).success(function () {
                    $('input:text:visible:first').focus();
                    $('#divLoading').hide();
                }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    $('#divLoading').hide();
                });
```

but model in controller is always null

Controler:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult PrepareSmsForOverview(ExtendedSmsListFormModel model)
{...
```

Comment: IMO you should keep it as $.ajax as $.post is just a shortcut and there is more flexibility in $.ajax

Answer (score 3):

Change your code this way:

```
$.post(url, $('#sms-form').serialize(), function (data) {
```

Comment: Your code is just missing request failing handler: `$.post(url, $('#sms-form').serialize(), function (data) {$('#myModal').modal();}).fail(function(){$('#divLoading').hide();});`